# Does display:none perform better then height:0?

Tags: jquery, html, css

we're planning a bit of a redesign of a project of us. One focus is on performance. Especially with that in mind I sketched 2 different UI-options and I'd like to know which one'll cost the user less CPU-power/runs smoother?
So classic scenario with a horizontal navigation group like

```
<nav><ul><li>Foo</li><li>Products</li><li>News></li><li>Contact</li></ul></nav>
```

and some hidden submenus therefore, like

```
<section class="submenu_products">
<h3>some content</h3><p>some content</p>
<ul>
<li>Sub-Product</li>
<li>Sub-Product 1</li>
<li>Sub-Product 2</li>
<li>Sub-Product 3</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

with **scenario 1**:

```
.submenu_products{
z-index:5;
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
}
```

and I'd show it with detecting the hover on the appropriate trigger and edit the css by hovering this to display:block;

or **scenario 2**:

```
.submenu_products{
display:none;
height:0;
}
```

and I'd show it with detecting the hover on the appropriate trigger and edit the css by hovering this to height:300px; transition:0.5s;

Now I am wondering which of these solutions would be the most performant ones and how can I detect something like this by myself?

For displaying both of the solutions I'd use either jquery or vanilla JS, no pure css-solution - so it's not the question what is a better alternative but simply which of the twos (or an optimized thing of the twos) is the more performing one.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have to support <IE8, why would you use javascript instead of [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover)?

Comment: I'd assume browser compatibility, but if that's the case, I'd hope touch screens are handled too ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracing `javascript performance`, you can use `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` as below:

```
// start timer
console.time("SOME_NAME");

// your logic/code here

// end timer
console.timeEnd("SOME_NAME");
```

The result will be in `ms`

Supported by: Firebug, the Webkit Inspector, Opera Dragonfly and IE11.

Answer (score 2):

An element with height: 0 will still 'appear' in the flow of the document. display: none, on the other hand, will not. An example of this is, which should hopefully explain a bit more, I have created below:

https://jsfiddle.net/5rdL3a7x/1/

raw code from fiddle:

```
<div> 
    <span>Span1</span>
    <div style="height:0;"></div>
    <span>Span2</span>
</div>

<div> 
    <span>Span3</span>
    <div style="display:none;"></div>
    <span>Span4</span>
</div>

<div> 
    <span>Span5</span>
    <div style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
    <span>Span6</span>
</div>
```

The first 2 spans have a div between them with height: 0. This will cause the spans to appear on separate lines as the divs default display is block, which will take up the entire width of its parent. The second 2 spans have a div between them with a display: none style. Notice how they now appear on the same line? If you still want the element to 'take up' the space but not appear, you can use visibility: hidden, as demonstrated in the third set of spans in the above example

In terms of performance, there is negligible difference if any. How the css is applied will have more impact (e.g [id=menuItem1] will perform slower than #menuItem1) but again, it is something that isn't monumental.